# jquery autocomplete position

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, position

I am having a issue with my autocomplete popup window.

Below is my autocomplete script

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete( 
        source:values
    })
});
```

Now this #search is in center of my screen and when type any value the autocomplte fuction providing the output to extreme left which is not visible(Although the functionality is working). I need to move this autocomplete suggesion box just below my #search.

Bleow is my #search position

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Please enter the value" style="position: absolute; right: 445px; top: 190px;" size="20"/>
```

This is inside a `div`.

Regards,
Anish

Comment: The issue is due to the related input being positioned absolutely. You will most likely need to position the autocomplete dropdown yourself when it is shown, based on the position of the `#search` element.

Comment: Does the div have a relative or absolute position?

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/z1vwm9bf/

Comment: Hello Rory, I tried below but didn't help

Comment: position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right top", collision: "flip" },   and  position: { my: "left bottom", at: "left top", collision: "flip" },   things is on both the option I can't see any significant change in the autocomplete box.. as-if the parameter is not taken at all..below is my complete code..   $ (function() {
   $ ("#search").autocomplete( 
   
   {
   position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right top", collision: "flip" },
   source:uris
            
     
   })
   });

Comment: Make sure your page have only one element with that 'search' id! Otherwise you will have that kind of errors with positioning ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the appendTo attribute. You can set an Id or Class to the input's parent div and append the autocomplete elements to it... It might fix your issue... and if not, it should be a better code anyways :)

HTML:

```
<div id="appendToHere">
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Please enter the value" style="position: absolute; right: 445px; top: 190px;" size="20"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete( {
        source:values,
        appendTo: "#appendToHere"
    })
});
```

Read more here
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo

and one more thing, that position:absolute can be the issue, try not adding that and see what happens

**And make sure you have only one element with that ID otherwise selector '#search' will be crazy ;)**

Answer (score 0):

only one syntax mistake I found in my observation, you missed `{` in options object of autocomplete.
**[See Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/0L5t6jd8/3/)**

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source:values
    })
});
```

JQuery UI will manage position automatically! I dint see any issue with that.

---

**EDIT:** 
You said the list was displaying at very beginning of the page. I'm thinking your layout css styles causing the issue.

Try below

1. Remove absolute position , left, right styles and see how is working?
2. Think why do you need those styles at input tag level, Why not to apply to its parent.
3. Try with [`appendTo' Option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) as suggested in B.J's answer.

Comment: Thanks Venkat, but as I mentioned the functionality is working fine and I am able to see the values... But somehow as you mentioned the position is not managing automatically, as the autocompleted values coming in extreme left and my search in someware  center..

Comment: Okay, I'll suggest some points in my answer. Try [`appendTo` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) Show me the source `values`

Comment: Hello Venket, I have done some changes in the htlml tags and created the complete output in <div>. Then used below positioning....<input type="text" id="search"  placeholder="Enter the value"   size="35" style="float: left;width:95%;position:relative;margin:7px"/> Its working now.. thank for your help